# Applying a dimension-reducing linear transform to a hyperellipsoid

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $\mathbf{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ be a positive definite matrix, and let $\Lambda$ be the set of points given by $$\Lambda = \{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^N: \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x} \leq 1\}.$$
$\Lambda$ is the set of points contained within the hyperellipsoid specified by $\mathbf{C}$.

I am interested in what happens if I apply a dimension-reducing linear transform to the elements in this set.  Specifically, let $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{Q \times N}$ be a linear transform with $Q < N$.  I am interested in obtaining a simple expression describing the new set of points $\Theta = \{\mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^Q : \exists \mathbf{x} \in \Lambda \text{ s.t. } \mathbf{z}=\mathbf{B}\mathbf{x}  \}.$

I know that this problem has a simple solution if $Q=N$ and $\mathbf{B}$ is nonsingular.  In that case, it is easy to show that $\Theta$ is simply the set of points $$\Theta = \{ \mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^Q: \mathbf{z}^T \mathbf{B}^{-T} \mathbf{C} \mathbf{B}^{-1} \mathbf{z} \leq 1\},$$
which is also a hyperellipsoid.

I suspect that $\Theta$ will also be a hyperellipsoid when $\mathbf{B}$ is a dimension-reducing ($Q < N$) linear transform, and while I can show this for a few specific cases, I don't know how to show this generally and I don't know how to come up with the general equation for the new hyperellipsoid describing $\Theta$.

Is it correct that $\Theta$ must be a hyperellipsoid, and if so, are there any suggestions on how to find the equation of that hyperellipsoid?  This may be a well-known result, but I don't know where to start looking, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks